# .htaccess Redirect Subfolder and all children to parent

Tags: .htaccess

I know this has probably been asked before, however i am trying to redirect some sub directories, and i can not see why it is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^news-updates/portfolio-tag/(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/news-updates/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

The URL that i am redirecting is:
`https://www.domain.co.uk/news-updates/portfolio-tag/` and all the child pages

Where am I going wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must indicate (by $1) the left-hand part that must be copied to the right:

```
RewriteRule ^news-updates/portfolio-tag/(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/news-updates/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Can not believe i was missing the last 2 characters. Thank you for you help! It works :)